# How to decrease value of a variable in smarty?

Tags: smarty, decrement

I'm having one varable named `$test_que_order` in my smarty template. It has assigned an integer value from PHP file. Now during further manipulation I'm passing the value of this varable in an URL. While passing the value I'm deresing it by one. Actually it's expected to decerease the value by one but in real it's not happening. I'm not getting why this is happening? Can anyone help me in this regard? Any help would be highly appreciated. For your reference I'm putting my smarty template code as below code as below. Please let me know wheteher I'm doing something wrong or the issue is something different else. Thanks in advance.

```
<input id="previous" class="c-btn" type="button" name="previous" value="Previous" onclick="javascript:window.location.href='{$control_url}modules/tests/manual_test_questions.php?op=previous&test_id={$test_id}&test_no_questions={$question_count}&test_que_order={$test_que_order - 1}'" {if $test_que_order == 1} disabled="disabled" {/if}/>
```

If you need any further information I can provide you the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code appends the value of the variable incremented by one to the output, but doesn't change the variable's actual value.

You can change the value of the variable for example like this:

```
{assign var=test_que_order value=$test_que_order-1}
```

or this way:

```
{$test_que_order = $test_que_order-1}
```

(You should add this solutions before your code snipet, and remove the `-1` from your snipet.)

Otherwise there is a suggestion here:

http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.assign.tpl

> Assignment of variables in-template is essentially placing application
>   logic into the presentation that may be better handled in PHP. Use at
>   your own discretion.